# Suppose $R$ is a relation on $A$. Let $B = P (A) $\ $\{\varnothing\}$, and deﬁne a relation $S$ on $B$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Suppose $R$ is a relation on $A$. Let $B = P (A) $\  $\{\varnothing\}$, and deﬁne a relation $S$ on $B$ as follows:

$S =\{ (X,Y)\in B \times B |\forall x \in X, \forall y \in Y,(xRy)\}.$

Prove that if $R$ is transitive, then so is $S$.

I'm stuck figuring out why is S not vacuously transitive in case we define $R = \{(1,2),(3,4)\}$ in order to prove it to be transitive

Comment: Doesn't you definition of B mean it contains only the empty set?

Comment: @user247327 Based on the original post, that must have been a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Statements of the form $\forall x \in \varnothing \colon ...$ are vacuously true, so if the empty set would be in $B$, then $(X, \varnothing), (\varnothing, X) \in S$ for any $X \in B$. So then if there are some $X, Y \in B$ with $(X, Y) \not\in S$ (we can always find such $X$ and $Y$ unless $xRy$ for all $x, y \in A$), then $S$ is not transitive since $(X, \varnothing), (\varnothing, Y) \in S$.

So it definitely is essential that $\varnothing \not\in B$ for the statement to be true.

Comment: what about the second part ?

Comment: I'm confused by the last part of your question; the point of these kinds of exercise is usually to prove it without knowing what $R$ is.

For this, take $X, Y, Z \in B$ and suppose $(X, Y), (Y, Z) \in S$. Then for all $x \in X, y \in Y$ and $z \in Z$, we have $xRy$ and $yRz$. We wish to prove that we also have $xRz$ for all $x \in X$ and $z \in Z$, since then $(X, Z) \in S$. You'll need transitivity of $R$ for this. Can you complete the proof?