# Why is it necessary to exclude empty set to accomplish this relation proof?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, relations

Working on the book: Daniel J. Velleman. "HOW TO PROVE IT: A Structured Approach, Second Edition" (p. 201)

> ∗20. Suppose $R$ is a relation on $A$. Let $B = \{X \in P (A) \colon X\neq\emptyset \}$, and define a relation $S$ on $B$ as follows:
> $S = \{(X,Y) \in B \times B \colon \forall x \in X, \forall y \in Y(xRy)\}$.
>
> Prove that if $R$ is transitive, then so is $S$. Why did the empty set have to
> be excluded from the set $B$ to make this proof work?

I am trying to find a counterexample to justify the exclusion of the empty set from this proof. So, I define:

- $R = \{(1,2), (2,1), (1,1), (2,2)\}$
- $A = \{1,2\}$
- $B = \{X \in P (A)\} = \{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2\}\}$

Can I find a suitable counterexample with these sets? Why does $S$ lose transitivity property if the empty set is not excluded ?

Comment: If you allow $\emptyset$ in $B$, then let us say you have to test whether $(\emptyset, Y) \in S$. For that you will need to test whether $xRy$ holds for all $x \in \emptyset$ and that is where the problem lies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suppose $R$ is a relation on $A$. Let $B = P (A) $\ $\{\varnothing\}$, and deﬁne a relation $S$ on $B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3547682/suppose-r-is-a-relation-on-a-let-b-p-a-varnothing-and-de%ef%ac%81ne)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that post. However, that answer did not fully address my question as I wanted to also know about my attempt for finding a counterexample. The question posted here helped me to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if $X=\varnothing$, then $\forall x\in X\,\forall y\in Y\,(xRy)$ is vacuously true for **every** $Y\subseteq A$. What could make it false? There would have to be some $x\in X$ and some $y\in Y$ such that $x\not Ry$. But if $X=\varnothing$, there isn’t any $x\in X$ at all, so it’s impossible for such a pair of $x$ and $y$ to exist.

Now take $X$ and $Y$ to be two subsets of $A$ such that $X\not S Y$. Then $XS\varnothing$ and $\varnothing SY$, but $X\not SY$, so $S$ is not transitive. Your example won’t work, because all subsets of your $A$ are related by $S$, but it could be changed easily enough; try $R=\{\langle 1,1\rangle,\langle 1,2\rangle,\langle 2,2\rangle\}$, the $\le$ relation on $A$, and $X=\{2\}$. (I’ll let you find a $Y$ such that $X\not SY$.)

Comment: Thank you, @Brian M. Scott ! One question: if $X = \emptyset$, that statement is vacuously true only when $Y = \emptyset$. So, both sets must equal the empty set for that statement. Is that correct ?

Comment: @F.Zer: No, by that condition is vacuously true whenever at least one of $X$ and $Y$ is empty.

Comment: Thank you ! That clarifies a doubt I had. Regarding the homework, the $Y$ you mentioned is the empty set ? Becuase, $(\{2\} S \emptyset \land \emptyset S\{1\}) \land \{2\} \not S\{1\}$. Does it show it loses transitivity ?

Comment: @F.Zer: No, if you take $Y=\varnothing$, then $\{2\}S\varnothing$, $\varnothing S\varnothing$, and $\{2\}S\varnothing$, so you don’t have a counterexample. But taking $Y=\{1\}$ works fine, just as you show in your comment.